# Multiple polymorphic associations on the same Model(s), how do I access the correct rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a model, **Post**, which has a *Posted* and a *Received* (I.E a Sender and a Recipient). Both *Posted* and *Received* can be either a **User** or a **Group**.

So

```
User.rb
  has_many :posts, as: :posted
  has_many :posts, as: :received

Group.rb
  has_many :posts, as: :posted
  has_many :posts, as: :received

Post.rb
  belongs_to :posted, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :received, polymorphic: true
```

Is this possible? It seems to make sense to me and I have no problem making a post, but I can't seem to access the posts to display.

I thought I could use: (but reading more on polymorphic associations.. I suspect I don't fully understand it)

```
@user.recieved do |post|
and
@user.posted do |post|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, you'll just need to differentiate the has_many association names:

```
User.rb
  has_many :posted_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :posted
  has_many :received_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :received

Group.rb
  has_many :posted_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :posted
  has_many :received_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :received

Post.rb
  belongs_to :posted, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :received, polymorphic: true
```

So, to use them:

```
@user.posted_posts do |post|

end

@user.received_posts do |post|

end
```

You can name the associations whatever you want, but keep in mind that you can't have more than one association with the same name on a model.

Comment: This looks like the answer, Thank you! To confirm, is there anything else I should be putting in my Model or Controller or do I let the rails framework handle the rest? I ask, because I've taken these steps and I still can't find any requests in the log for the Post table.